# Missing Properties option in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

in trying to fix a different problem in VS 2008 I've been instructed to go to the 'web' tab which is found by right clicking on the project in the solution explorer and going to 'properties'.  However, when I right click on what I believe to be the project in the solutions explorer there is no 'properties' option available.  Instead there is a 'property pages' option, but this has no 'web' tab.  The thing I'm right clicking on is at the top of the solution explorer and its icon consists of 2 overlaid pages which are in turn overlaying a globe.  I'm pretty sure its the project (it is the parent of everything else in the file tree) but I could be wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using web project or web site ? With "web site" type of project there is no project property pages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx#webapplicationprojects
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763180.aspx

Comment: I didn't actually create the project just checked it out from source control, is there some definitive way to tell which type of project it is?  I'm guessing that its web site though since the first two options if I right click on the project are 'build web site' and 'publish web site'.

Comment: Locate directory of your project (e.g. where web.config is). Look for *.csproj file. If there then it's a web project. If missing you have web site.

Comment: In solution explorer web sites are seen as "C:\...\WebsSite1", while web project are displayed as any other project.